# C++ Calling a non-virtual method from an implemented virtual class

Tags: c++, methods, interface, virtual

i have an interface that also has a normal method, how do i call that then?

```
class Animal{
   virtual void virtualFunction()=0;
}

class Cow : Animal{
   virtual void virtualFunction(){}
   void nonVirtualFunction(){}
}

class main{
   Animal *a = new Cow();
   a->virtualFunction();
}
```

^: **THIS works**, but when i do...

```
a->nonVirtualFunction();
```

it says that the class *Animal doesn't have this method*, i know that ofcourse, 
but **what way is best to call that method**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're going to call a function that is a member of `Cow`, don't store it in a polymorphic `Animal` pointer in the first place:

```
Cow* c = new Cow();
c->nonVirtualFunction();
```

It doesn't make sense to store a `Cow` in an `Animal*` if you're going to use it in a `Cow`-specific way.

You *can* use `dynamic_cast` to check the dynamic type of an object at run time:

```
Animal* a = new Cow();
if (Cow* c = dynamic_cast<Cow*>(a)) {
  c->nonVirtualFunction();
}
```

However, this is usually a sign of bad design.

Comment: Thanks indeed, didn't know that, i will use the Cow* c = new Cow(); indeed!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a Cow pointer to call nonVirtualFunction. The Animal pointer is a pointer to the SUBSET of the Cow that has the interface of an Animal.

The ONLY way to call nonVirtualFunction is to get a Cow pointer.

```
Cow *c = dynamic_cast<Cow*>(a);
```

will give you such a pointer, assuming that a really does point to a Cow.

Answer (score 1):

I will use real names for the methods instead of placeholders in order to explain myself better:

```
class Animal{
   virtual void move()=0;
}

class Cow : Animal{
   virtual void move(){}
   void moo(){}
}

int main () {
   Animal *a = new Cow();
   a->move();
   a->moo(); // ERROR
}
```

Well, of course that's an error: why on earth would you want to make a generic `Animal` `moo`? So the problem is not how to call `moo` on any `Animal`; it just happens that this call is meaningless and the compiler helps us noticing.

Now, an `Animal` may have a non-virtual method that can be called on any animal with no need to rewrite it on subclasses, for instance:

```
class Animal{
   // Everything else, plus:
   std::string Name() {return name;}

private:
   std::string name;
}

int main () {
   Animal *a = new Cow();
   a->move();
   std::string animalName = a->Name(); // OK
}
```

As you can see, if you have a good design the problem disappears.

Comment: Hmm indeed, your way with real names instead of placeholders is indeed clearer! will do that :)
But thanks, have the answer now indeed, should just make a cow *c = new cow!